# Kafka REST Proxy installation

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Im trying to install Kafka REST Proxy from the following URL however it has complete package - I just want to install REST client alone as other components I have installed already

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp.html#zip-and-tar-archives

Is there any place where I can find instructions?

Comment: Do you mean the REST Proxy? https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html

Comment: Yes but the link has whole platform I just want REST Proxy installation.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited your question to make it clear

Comment: How exactly did you install the other components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [individual packages available](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/available_packages.html#component-packages) - you should be able to install just `confluent-kafka-rest`.

Or, just install full Confluent Platform and only start the REST Proxy, same net effect :)